# Is the .each iterator in ruby guaranteed to give the same order on the same elements every time?

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

I'm doing something like this with a list 'a':

```
a.each_with_index |outer, i|
  a.each_with_index |inner, j|
    if(j > i)
      # do some operation with outer and inner
    end
  end
end
```

if the iterator is not going to use the same order, this won't work. I don't care what the order actually is, I just need for two .each_with_index iterators to use the same order.

I would assume that it would be a property of an array that it has a fixed order and I'm just being paranoid that the iterator wouldn't use that order...

Comment: When you say "list", do you mean "array", or could you also mean "set"?

Comment: In this case, it is an array. I have some sets, too, though. I suppose I was wondering if .each would imply an order, but it makes more sense to assume that only an ordered collection would be in order...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This depends on the specific `Enumerable` object you are operating on.

Arrays for example will always return elements in the same order. But other enumerable objects are not guaranteed to behave this way. A good example of this is the 1.8,7 base Hash. That is why many frameworks (most notably ActiveSupport) implement an OrderedHash.

One interesting side note: Even `Hash` will return objects in the same order if the hash has not changed between `each` calls. While many objects behave this way, relying on this subtlety is probably not a great idea.

So, no. The generic `each` will not always return objects in the same order.

P.S. Ruby 1.9's hashes are now actually ordered http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash

Answer (score 7):

I've not looked at your actual code but here is your answer taken from the [Ruby API docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html):

> Arrays are ordered, integer-indexed collections of any object.

So yes, you are being paranoid but surely that's a good thing when you're developing?

Comment: I guess my concern is that the iterator could (for some reason?) change the order...

Answer (score 2):

Array by definition is an ordered list of elements. So you should have no problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific Enumerable. Certainly an Array will always iterate in the obvious order.

It would be quite lunatic fringe for someone to implement an `each` method that would traverse the same collection in different ways, but the only actual restriction for such a "feature" would be in the documentation for the class that mixes in Enumerable. Well, in that and the sanity of the implementors.

I can almost imagine some sort of cryptographic API that deliberately traversed a collection in an unpredictable way.

Comment: Also for statistical tests it is useful to randomly traverse enumerables...