# What are .each iterator fetch order guarantees?

Tags: ruby

I am really baffled by something as it led in hours of head scratching; I have the following segment of code

```
objectA.arrayA.each do |p|
  do stuff with p
end
```

I thought this was fine, since from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590152/is-the-each-iterator-in-ruby-guaranteed-to-give-the-same-order-on-the-same-elem) I felt that since I am using an array for the job so I should be fine. Unfortunately that was not the case since the order that the each iterator returned the elements was not always the same. After hours of looking at other blocks for the issue swapping the above code with this for loop solved the problem:

```
for i in 0...objectA.arrayA.length
  do stuff with the array element
end
```

Anyone has any idea when the ordering of each is *guaranteed*?

Comment: The `do stuff with p` is probably important here. Were you doing any modifications on the array elements in that loop?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski well, I am not touching the elements of the array what I am doing is some if checks but I am not touching the actual values or order; like i.e. `if p.x == 1` increment a value outside the array. hope this helps.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum working example that demonstrates this?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy Well, you can easily view that yourself; I am trying to modify this code here  https://code.google.com/p/su2espr/source/browse/trunk/su2espr.rb and the lines in question are 141-146. The code in that link has many issues but you can run it easily.

Comment: Sure, but can you also provide an exact array and point that you found to work this way. If we can't replicate the problem it's hard to proceed any further with it.

Comment: I just pointed you to the actual source... this runs inside Sketchup so I can't just find a discrete working example; if you import that source in Sketchup change those lines with the .each iterator method you'll stumble across what I said above.

Comment: My computer doesn't meet the requirements for sketchup, so I guess I'll leave it for someone else to look at.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and the *shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You are expecting us to install random third-party software and sift through hundreds of lines of code, just because you can't be bothered to …

Comment: … demonstrate your problem in a couple of lines. That is not exactly polite towards people who spend their free time to do your work for you without even getting paid for it.

Comment: I didn't ask you or anyone to do my work; I asked for a clarification on a language guarantee. Stop being offensive, besides I am not expecting anything; if you cannot or are not willing to answer/contribute to the question just skip it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html) state

> The Enumerable mixin provides collection classes with several
>   traversal and searching methods, and with the ability to sort. The
>   class must provide a method each, which **yields successive members** of
>   the collection. If Enumerable#max, #min, or #sort is used, the objects
>   in the collection must also implement a meaningful <=> operator, as
>   these methods rely on an ordering between members of the collection.

So `Array.each` must also yield successive members to meet this contract

If an implementation doesn't enforce this, it would be a bug in the implementation